# Fix page numbering format for latex listings package (lstlistoflistings)

Tags: listings, page-numbering

I have a problem with the listings of my latex document. I am using the "listing**s**" package (not the "listing" package).

Although the pagenumbering is still set to "roman" right after the titlepage, the \lstlistoflistings command produces a page where the numbering is "arabic". Apparently I am not the only one with [that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709898/change-list-of-listings-text). Is this maybe a bug of the listings package? Can somebody help me with this?

Here is a code sample of my .tex file.

```
    ...
    \begin{document}
    \dominitoc[e] 
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \include{titlepage}

    \pagenumbering{roman}

    \include{firstquote} % page numbering ok "i"
    \include{preamble} % page numbering ok "ii"

    \pagestyle{headings} 

    \include{abstract}

    \begin{spacing}{1.2}

        \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents % page numbering ok "iii"
        \listoffigures % page numbering ok "iv"
        \listoftables % page numbering ok "v"
        \lstlistoflistings % here is the page that produces de problem, page numbering "1"

    \end{spacing}

    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \addtolength{\parskip}{0.25\baselineskip}

    \include{chapters/01-introduction}
    ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have reset the page numbering to `\arabic` by `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. The page numbering style is used that is active, when the page is shipout. Add a `\newpage`, `\clearpage`, or `\cleardoublepage` before.

```
\begin{spacing}{1.2}
  ...
  \lstlistoflistings
\end{spacing}
\cleardoublepage % or \newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Consider using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, if you are using a document class that provides it (`book`, `memoir`, …). These commands take care of starting new pages and the page numbering.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. This did the trick!

Comment: thank you so much for that !